# MultiIndex from Pivot Tuple Index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that I created from a data frame, the index is a tuple `(["Warehouse", "Month"])`, however when I run:

`multi.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pivoted.index)`

I receive the following error:

`TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`

Full Code Below:

```
hedrows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in hedrows :
    total_issues = total_issues + 1
issue_df = pd.read_sql(issue_query, cnxn)
issue_df.rename(columns={'00001' : 'Invoices', 'OBWHID' : 'Warehouse', 'OBRTRC':'Reason', 'INV_MONTH':'Month', '00005':'Date'}, inplace=True)
pivoted = pd.pivot_table(issue_df, index=["Warehouse", "Month"], values=["Invoices"], columns=['Reason'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
warehouse_percentages=pivoted
total_percentages=pivoted
warehouse_percentages=pivoted
total_percentages=pivoted
#Percentages of Warehouse Returns by Month
warehouse_percentages =  100 * warehouse_percentages[:].div(warehouse_percentages[:].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
pivoted.loc['Column Total'] = pivoted.sum()
#Percentages of Total Returns by Month
total_percentages = total_percentages.div(total_issues)
multi.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pivoted.index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set

```
pivoted.loc['Column Total'] = pivoted.sum()
```

your DataFrame goes from having a MultiIndex something like

```
In [1]: pivoted
                 CE  CS  DG  DR  IC  IO
Warehouse Month                        
01        01      9   4   6   5   6   6
02        02      5   3   2   1   3   1

In [2]: pivoted.index
Out[2]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['01', '02'], ['01', '02']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]],
           names=['Warehouse', 'Month'])
```

to having an index of `dtype='object'` comprised of tuples from the previous index and your new `'Column Total'` string.

```
In [3]: pivoted.loc['Column Total'] = pivoted.sum()

In [4]: pivoted
Out[4]: 
              CE  CS  DG  DR  IC  IO
(01, 01)       9   4   6   5   6   6
(02, 02)       5   3   2   1   3   1
Column Total  14   7   8   6   9   7

In [5]: pivoted.index
Out[5]: Index([('01', '01'), ('02', '02'), 'Column Total'], dtype='object')
```

Now as `'Column Total'` is evidently a string and not a tuple, it should be clear why you are getting that error - [`from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) expects a list of tuples, not a list of tuples and a string.

I'm not entirely sure what your desired behavior is here or what you are doing, but I would maybe suggest *not* adding the column sums as a row in your MultiIndex unless you have a good reason to. If you need the sums for some aggregation, you could always calculate them at that point in time, or store them in a separate Series.

In any case, you could add a total row (which is invalidated as soon as you manipulate your DataFrame of course) and retain your MultiIndex with something like

```
In [6]: df.loc[('Total', 'Total'), :] = df.sum()

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
                   CE   CS   DG   DR   IC   IO
Warehouse Month                               
01        01      9.0  4.0  6.0  5.0  6.0  6.0
02        02      5.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  3.0  1.0
Total     Total  14.0  7.0  8.0  6.0  9.0  7.0
```